# KeyError: "['China'] not in index"

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I am trying to select China's nationality tourists, this is my code snippet-

```py
import pandas as pd 

China = ses[(ses["S1Country"] == 1)]
List_China = China[['Case','S1Country']]
List_China

This is what i put before the error
```

Here I am trying to selecting certain data - most sources that people used, the code snippet to perform it-

```py
import pandas as pd 

Ranking1 = ses[(ses["Q7Infor1"] == 1)]
List_Ranking1 = Ranking1[['China','Q7Infor1']]
List_Ranking1
```

Then I wrote this code and it reported back to me
`'KeyError: "['China'] not in index'`

How do I solve it?
Thanks for checking in!

sample of the data:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your dataframe? How do your rows and columns look like?

Comment: Kindly provide a minimal reproducible example, How do you expect us to solve without a sample dataframe.

Comment: it doesnt work tho,.. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to filter the column `Q7Infor1` by the value `China`, then you can use `df[df['col'] == value]`.

Thus, your original code:

```py
List_Ranking1 = Ranking1[['China','Q7Infor1']]
```

Becomes this:

```py
List_Ranking1 = Ranking1[Ranking1['Q7Infor1'] == 'China']
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165056/5305519) on the different ways you can filter a column by a row value.

---

**Updated with OP's dataset**

'China' is not a valid value in column `Q7Infor1`. So assuming that `China=1`, then we can filter by value 1:

```py
China = 1
List_Ranking1 = Ranking1[Ranking1['Q7Infor1'] == China]
```

To count number of rows:

```py
print(len(List_Ranking1))
```

Comment: Hi!! what i am trying to do is to get the data from the China data tho... like i have selected china data from the cases and i am trying to rank the interests by finding the data from china again but it does not seem to work...

Comment: I see, can you edit your answer and provide us with some sample data?

Comment: can i attach file?

Comment: Updated answer with your dataset

Comment: but i wanna know the number of times it appeared to be rank 1 ...

Comment: Updated to include count number of rows

Comment: so the output means that the ranking number 1 has appeared 48 times in the data of china column only?